# Trying to update the background image of a UIButton on click

Tags: swift3, uibutton, background-image

I have a button with a set background image. It's a png with most of the image being transparent. When that image is tapped on (selected), I would like to update the background image of the button to a different image. It seems to be working, but it's not removing the original background image. It seems to be placing the new background image behind the old one. So the transparent background image seems to be above the selected background image.

Setting the background image:

```
owedTotalBtn.setBackgroundImage( UIImage.init(named:"total-owed"), for: .normal)
```

Updating the background image one the button is tapped:

```
@IBAction func showOwed(_ sender: Any) { 
 owedTotalBtn.setBackgroundImage( UIImage.init(named:"total-owed-selected"), for: .normal)

}
```

Comment: when you initially set your image on your `UIButton`, did you accidentally set the image property instead of setting the background image?

Comment: Thanks @Michael, that is exactly what I did.

Answer (score 0):

You have set background Image for both normmal state. Try this code:

```
owedTotalBtn.setBackgroundImage( UIImage.init(named:"total-owed"), for: .normal)
owedTotalBtn.setBackgroundImage( UIImage.init(named:"total-owed"), for: .selected)

@IBAction func showOwed(_ sender: Any) { 
 sender.isSelected = !sender.isSelected

}
```